# How can I create a partitioned table that is semicolumn separated and has commas as decimal points?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm having problems whith this type of table:

```
    manager;    sales
    charles;    100,1
    ferdand;    212,6
    aldalbert;  23,4
    chuck;      41,6
```

I'm using the code bellow to create and define the partitioned table:

```
    CREATE TABLE db.table
    (
        manager string,
        sales string
        ) 
    partitioned by (file_type string)  
    row format delimited  fields terminated by ';'  
    lines terminated by '\n'  
    tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

Afterwards, I'm using a regex command to replace the commas by dots and then convert the *sales* field to a number datatype. 
I wonder if there is a better solution than that.

Comment: I am afraid there isn't any. However you file as two column and table has three.

Comment: A "betterish" solution could be to use two distinct tables: an EXTERNAL table to read these CSV files (with String columns); a managed table, using a more efficient storage format i.e. ORC/Parquet, and typed columns; plus an `INSERT OVERWRITE SELECT` query to apply the necessary transformations. In short, that would be an ELT _(Extract, Load, Transform)_ process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than using Spark or Pig to clean the data as well as load the Hive table, then no, you'll need to replace and cast the sales column within HiveQL to get the format you want